# Add comma to count of job / companies

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Adding a comma would help readability here:

[image]

Comment: Or should we do 10k in true Stack Overflow style?

Comment: Jason, if you do 10k, you lose the precision, I am okay with that as long as you guys are ok with that.  Meaning 10428 jobs is much different than 10k jobs.

Comment: Eh, now that I'm thinking about it we put the full precision number for questions and comma it, so we'll just do that...

Comment: Maybe if you do <b>over</b> 10k company pages...That could work too to handle the anal programmers who state there are more than just 10k.

Comment: @JasonPunyon - I'd agree with you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the commas. Enjoy them.